# SICP 1.31: Approximating Pi

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

I'm working through SICP on my own, so I don't have an instructor to ask about this. This code is supposed to approximate pi but always returns zero instead.

```
(define (approx-pi acc)
  (define (factors a)
    (define basic-num
         (if (= (mod a 2) 0)
             (/ a 2)
             (/ (- a 1) 2)))
    (if (= (mod basic-num 2) 0)
      basic-num
      (/ 1 basic-num)))
  (* 4 (product factors 5 (* 2 acc))))
```

Here are the mod and product procedures that are referenced in this code. These don't seem to be the problem but I'll include them just in case.

```
(define (product func lo hi)
  (define (product-iter i result)
    (if (> i hi)
      result
      (product-iter (+ 1 i) (* result (func i)))))
  (product-iter 1 1))

(define (mod a b)
  (if (< (- a b) 0)
    a
    (mod (- a b) b)))
```

The whole thing is an implementation of the formula:

pi / 4 = (2 * 4 * 4 * 6 ...) / (3 * 3 * 5 * 5 ... )

My mistake is obviously something pretty stupid, but I'm new to Scheme so I can't find it.
If anyone has any stylistic tips, I'd really appreciate that, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your product function has a subtle flaw:

```
(product + 4 5)
```

returns 120 when the correct answer is 20.
The reason is

```
(product-iter 1 1) should be (product-iter lo 1)
```

Comment: Ah, that was the problem exactly. I should have known that it's a bad sign when I don't use all of my formal parameters. Now everything works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the call to `product-iter` in the function `product`, it will do 
`(* 1 (factor 1))` right in the first iteration, which will evaluate to 0 because `(factor 1)` is 0. Therefore, the total product will be 0 as well.

Comment: You're right- I really just forgot to implement the lower starting range in the product function.